# React: Select body part from image

Tags: reactjs, image

I want to build a website with React on which you can select different parts of a body. I would like to ask for your opinion what would be the best possibility for that? How can I highlight different parts of the body and make them clickable?

I would image a screen like this where I can press e.g. an arm, leg, head etc.: [image: body-parts]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One approach would be to split the image up into many images, and use hover/click to select each image

Answer (score 0):

You will need two images.

1. Original colour body shape ( let's call this passive state ).
2. Active colour body shape.

Create a grid of rectangles on top of passive state image according to body parts, slice the active body shape image and put in rectangles as background images and set the image size to 0. On hover just set the size of the image to the original value.

Comment: Ok thank you! What do you mean with set image size to 0? Why should I set the size of the image to original value on hover?

Comment: the idea is to hide and show images inside rectangles, there are many ways to do that one of which can be to set background-size to 0 and on hovering div set size to original, you can use other techniques with the same success, for example putting img tags inside div and setting property display to none initially and on div hover set display to block.